# which trigger fires when press default insert record button oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

which trigger fires when press the default insert record button in oracle forms 6i? I need to know available triggers which will fires when or after pressing the default insert record button in oracle forms building with oracle forms builder 6i.

[image: this is the button I mean]

Answer (score 1):

Many triggers may fire.  When you press (any) button, when-button-pressed will fire.  If the button recieves focus, you may fire when-validate-item as you leave the previous item, and possibly when-new-item-instance as you enter the button

Then on the block there are pre-insert, on-insert, and post-insert all of which could fire if defined.

Alternatively, if you are referring to *create* record, ie, open up a new blank row, then you'd be looking at when-new-record-instance

Comment: will you please see the image and just tell me which triggres will be fired when i press that button. thank you @Connor